# Getting Database Error while login

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

when i update my project from codeigniter 2 to codeigniter 3.1.0 am getting error like this

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'SET `last_activity` = 1475123991, `user_data` =
>   'a:5:{s:8:\"identity\";s:5:\"adm' at line 1

```
UPDATE SET `last_activity` = 1475123991, `user_data` = 'a:5:{s:8:\"identity\";s:5:\"admin\";s:8:\"username\";s:5:\"admin\";s:5:\"email\";s:15:\"admin@admin.com\";s:7:\"user_id\";s:1:\"1\";s:14:\"old_last_login\";s:10:\"1475123252\";}' WHERE `session_id` = '6e963e57c9a5f087a5fcd39d9e2cdaa8'
```

> Filename: C:/wamp64/www/hosteliam/system/database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 691`

this is my line no 691
 `return $this->display_error(array('Error Number: '.$error['code'], $error['message'], $sql));`

had gone through many ways but didnt find a proper solution and dont now actually from where the error occurs

Answer (score 1):

There needs to be a table name in the UPDATE statement

```
  UPDATE tablename SET col = ... 
         ^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the table_name.

```
UPDATE table_name SET `last_activity` = 1475123991, `user_data` = 'a:5:{s:8:\"identity\";s:5:\"admin\";s:8:\"username\";s:5:\"admin\";s:5:\"email\";s:15:\"admin@admin.com\";s:7:\"user_id\";s:1:\"1\";s:14:\"old_last_login\";s:10:\"1475123252\";}' WHERE `session_id` = '6e963e57c9a5f087a5fcd39d9e2cdaa8'
```

Comment: where i should change

Comment: @MOHAMMED: One change you could make is to add an actual *question* to the "question" that you posted.

Comment: @MOHAMMED: Next to UPDATE, you need to put a table_name. Right before SET.